# Quering data in !cdata under xml document with xpath

Tags: xpath

Can I have the query (xpath) for getting the ISBN  value ( isbn ...>

```
 <description>
<![CDATA[
<img alt="Japon et fait colonial" src="http://cipango.revues.org/docannexe/file/1514/cip18-small200.jpeg" />
<div class="information"> <div class="isbn">ISBN 978-2-85831-195-8</div> </div> 
<div class="introduction" lang="fr"> <p>La colonisation moderne, qui d&#233;bute au
]]>
<![CDATA[...]]>
</description>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? XPath 1.0 or 2.0? In what environment are you using XPath?

Comment: xpath 2, Php 5 on linux ( ubuntu ). In Drupal CMS

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/description/substring-before(substring-after(text(), 'class=&quot;isbn&quot;>'), '&lt;')
```